# header and footer from html in html2pdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, html2pdf

I use my HTML code for the footer and header in html2pdf. I use this code, it works perfectly but it just shows plain text and I want to have my HTML code and style here.

```js
html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toContainer().toCanvas().toPdf().get('pdf').then((pdf) => {
var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();


// console.log("getHeight:" + pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight());
// console.log("getWidth:" + pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth());
for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
    pdf.setPage(i);

    pdf.setFontSize(10);
    pdf.setTextColor(150);

    //  pdf.text(footerCR,totalPages, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() /1.15, 
    // pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() /1.05);
    pdf.text(`${i} von${totalPages}`, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() / 1.15,
        pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() / 1.05);
    pdf.setTextColor(10);
    pdf.text('www.jms-gruppe.ch', pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() / 15,
        pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() / 1.05);
    pdf.text('Hydraulik und Druckluftschläuche', pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() / 3,
        pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() / 1.05);
    // pdf.text('page_header', pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() /9, 
    // pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() /15);
}
}).save();
});
```

Comment: I don't see where you try to set HTML

Comment: hi justinas
i don't know how and where schuld i set my html